# R regex for matching where string does not start with

Tags: r, string

I need a regex for `str_remove()` that removes all characters after and including `" - "` but only for strings that do not start with a number. For example, it should turn

`"d_19 - blah"`
into
`"d_19"`

but leave
`"1 - blah"`
unaffected

Comment: another one `gsub('(^(\\d.*|\\S+))|.', '\\1', x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R:

```
sub("^(\\D.*) -.*", "\\1", string)
[1] "d_19"     "1 - blah"
```

Using perl in base R

```
sub("^\\D.*\\K -.*", "", string, perl=TRUE)
[1] "d_19"     "1 - blah"
```

using `str_replace`

```
str_replace(string, "^(\\D.*) -.*", "\\1")
[1] "d_19"     "1 - blah"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it is somethimes easier to read if the regex is not too complex, so I simplified the task by excluding the untouchable elements first

```
x <- c("d_19 - blah", "1 - blah")

# which elements start with a number
x_num <- !grepl("^[0-9]", x)

# remove everything starting from the dash from all other elements
x[x_num] <- trimws(stringr::str_remove(x[x_num], "-.+"))

x
#> [1] "d_19"     "1 - blah"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
gsub('^\\D.*\\K\\s\\-.*', '', x, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "d_19"     "1 - blah"
```